# how to binding a event handler to a element being created?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In my page,I have to create some elements dymamiclly according use's operation,for example,when user click a button,I will create a new div,but I want to add a click handler to this div:

```
function createNewDiv(){
  var str="<aid='na'>xxx</a>";
  //add click handler to this a
  var ele=document.getElementById("na");
  if(ele.attachEvent){
    ele.attachEvent("onclick",function(){xxxx});
  }else if(ele.addEventListener){
    ele.addEventListener("click",function(){xxx},false);
  }
  document.getElementById("con").innerHTML="s";
}
```

When I run this code,I get the error:

ele is not defined.

Maybe this is caused that when I use the

```
var ele=document.getElementById("na")
```

THe html dom is under building,so it can not find the element.(I think this is why we use the jquery.ready(xxx).

If so,is there any idea to make it work?

I use Prototype 1.4 in my app.

---

Thanks for all the answers.

Now use the `<a>` instead the `<div>`

However for somea reason,I can not use the dom to build my element,that's to say,I can not use:

```
var div_n=document.createElement("a");
a.id="na";
......
```

Instead,I have to use the:

```
var s="<a id='na'>xxx</a>";

//append this created link to the existed container
document.getElementById("con").innerHTML=s;

//then how to add the click handler to the `a#na`?
```

Comment: Is the getElementById supposed to be the same id as the div you are creating? The comments say that you are trying to add a click handler to the new div but the id is different. It won't make a difference in whether it works or not, I'm just trying to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi,I update my post,I want to add click handler to the new created div.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. I replied with my answer, which I guess was the right one because 2 other people posted the same answer after me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What element are you trying to get into `ele`? If I understand your problem, you want to add an event to a `div` you are creating, and that `div` has the `id = nDiv`, so why are you trying to get an element with `id = con`? If you are trying to bind an event to your created div, maybe you can do it this way:

```
function createNewDiv(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'nDiv';
  //add click handler to this div
  div.addEventListener("click",function(){xxx},false);
  div.innerHTML="s";
}
```

If you have problems binding the function (I don't think so), try defining your function and bind it to the click this way:

```
function foo(){xxx}
...
div.addEventListener("click",foo,false);
...
```

Note that there are no parenthesis when binding the `foo` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the div using the DOM instead. That will make it immediately available to add the event handler. Example:

```js
function createNewDiv(){
  var ele = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id","nDiv");

  // ...

  document.getElementById("con").appendChild( ele );
}
```

Side note:

Doing this using the DOM is also much faster and much more standards complaint than innerHTML. But people tend to use innerHTML because it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="<div id="nDiv">xxx</div>"
```

Before looking further, is this part of the issue? I'm not sure what it does, but it's not valid unless you escape the inner quotation marks.

Anyway, I'm not sure exactly what your code is doing, but what you want to do should look something like this:

```
// Get a container element for wherever you're going to add these divs
var container = document.getElementById("con");

function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  // assign properties to div
  div.onclick = someFunction;
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR64/)